# how to add a header file and include it in cxxdroid android app or termux

Tags: c++, header-files, termux

hi  I'm new to c++ coding and I'm asking how to create and include a header file in a c++ program on Android, I've looked online on how to create the header file but whenever I include it with the complete path the compiler gives me a fatal error file not found message,whether I'm using termux emulator or CXXDROID IDE, I don't know why this is the case.

please help me because I'm stuck with this problem for days and I need to solve it in order for me to write meaningful programs as I'm using Programming Principles and Practice Using C++ Second Edition by Bjarne Stroustrup which uses a lot of user defined functions for the projects.

thanks in advance.

I've included the complete path of the header files and created the proper headers,

Comment: Recommendation: Stroustrup;'s book teaches C++ as you would write it in a common, non-dialectic environment. Don't try writing code for an embedded or semi embedded environment. Teach your self to write good C++ on a generic PC, then start doing the more3 interesting stuff.

Comment: user4581301 but it's hard to write a code without headers and I don't even have a pc, plus most exercises depend on user created headers and functions

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it in Termux. (And any other system/app where you have a c++ compiler)

Let's assume you have these files in your project.

```bash
main.cpp lib.h
```

Inside lib.h you have this code

```c
int myfunction(int agr1);
```

Then inside your `main.c` file you can reference it like this

```c
// Note the quotes
// Local header files need to be 
// referenced like this with their
// relative path
#include "lib.h"

int main(){
...
}

int myfunction(int arg1){
    // Implement your function here
}
```

You can now access your functions defined in your lib.h file from your main.cpp file.